# cv2 drawMatches draws on blank screen?

Tags: python, opencv

```
imageCorrespondence = cv2.drawMatches(imageLeft, kpLeft, imageRight, kpRight, [goodMatches[0]], None, flags=2)
cv2.imwrite('imageCorrespondence.png', imageCorrespondence)
```

gives expected output in jupyter notebook, but when I save the file using python script, it is drawing matches and `flags=4` is drawing keypoints just fine, except everything is happening on a black image (of right size: left + right combined).

[image]

Possible backend selection issues like we have with `matplotlib`?

---

The example code works just fine:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

def getCorrespondence(imageLeft, imageRight):
    orb = cv2.ORB_create()
    kpLeft, desLeft = orb.detectAndCompute(imageLeft, None)
    kpRight, desRight = orb.detectAndCompute(imageRight, None)

    bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING, crossCheck=True)
    matches = bf.match(desLeft, desRight)

    goodMatches = []
    for m in matches:
        if m.distance < 100:
            goodMatches.append(m)

    print('Matches', len(goodMatches))

    imageCorrespondence = cv2.drawMatches(imageLeft, kpLeft, imageRight, kpRight, [goodMatches[0]], None, flags=2)
    return imageCorrespondence

if __name__ == '__main__':
    imageLeft = cv2.imread('image_001.png')
    imageRight = cv2.imread('image_002.png')

    imageCorrespondence = getCorrespondence(imageLeft, imageRight)
    cv2.imwrite('imageCorrespondence.png', imageCorrespondence)
    print('Image Saved')
```

But as soon as I start using the function with other images loaded from elsewhere, it is breaking something. I made sure if those images have content and `cv2.imwrite('imageLeft', imageLeft)` works just fine and the image gets saved fine.

Comment: Provide a [mcve]. Shouldn't have to remind a 5 year user with reputation in thousands about that....

Comment: Sorry, I thought I missed something in those two lines I posted initially (esp because I set the output image param to None) which I assumed would be obvious to opencv users, hence didn't add the full code. Added it now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I initially thought the sixth param `None` was causing this, but that is not causing any trouble.

`cv2.drawMatches()` takes in imageLeft and imageRight as numpy arrays as mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d5d/group__features2d__draw.html#ga7421b3941617d7267e3f2311582f49e1):

> ```
> outImg    =   cv.drawMatches( img1, keypoints1, img2, keypoints2, matches1to2, outImg[, matchColor[, singlePointColor[, matchesMask[,flags]]]]    )
> ```
>
> Parameters
>
> - `img1`  First source image.
> - `keypoints1`    Keypoints from the first source image.
> - `img2`  Second source image.
> - `keypoints2`    Keypoints from the second source image. ...

However something that breaks this is the alpha layer, if you happen to load the alpha layer in the numpy array, it would draw on a black image. When I removed the alpha layer in the numpy array manually and had only three channels, it started working fine. This could be because of the way `matplotlib` handles alpha layer differs from how `cv2.imwrite` handles the same, that it seemed to work in Jupyter notebook but not using the Python script.

I initially thought I needed to switch from BGRA to ABGR, but that's not the case BGRA is just fine, I was getting a black screen if the input images had a fourth alpha layer. **Opencv usually strips the alpha layer** when reading an image...!

Comment: Good catch. Looking at the source code, [here is the culprit](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/ef5579dc8667e5eb5e149acc4af898421eed99da/modules/features2d/src/draw.cpp#L176) and [here's another](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/ef5579dc8667e5eb5e149acc4af898421eed99da/modules/features2d/src/draw.cpp#L120). The random colour generation leaves the alpha channel at default value of 0, so whatever it draws ends up transparent. I'll file a bug report, this is a trivial fix.

Comment: And one more: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/13227 | Fix for the previous issue is already merged, should be fine in 3.4.5 and the next release of 4.x. I guess this is really what you ran into.